# How to print DataFrames from list of DataFrame side by side in notebook, Please note that the number of DataFrames in the list is unknown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

We are having one list of DataFrames, need to print all the DataFrames side by side in notepad.

Assume the DataFrames are:

```
DF1:
    Alpha   Num
0   D   68 
1   E   69 
2   F   70 

DF2:
    Alpha   Num
0   A   65
1   B   66 
2   C   67
```

the above dataFrames are in one list: "df_list"

Now we need to print these DataFrames using list as below:

```
    Alpha   Num             Alpha   Num
 0   D      68       0       A       65
 1   E      69       1       B       66
 2   F      70       2       C       67
```

**Please note that the number of DataFrames in the list is unknown**
pd.concat is merging both DataFrames & making single DataFrame which is not the requirement

Comment: Use `pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)`.

Comment: pd.concat is merging both DataFrames & making single DataFrame which is not the requirement

Comment: Then what is the requirement?

Comment: Want to print the DataFrames side by side

Comment: Combine all data frames using `pd.concat` into one and print it. I don't understand where the problem is? This will be much cleaner than writing a complicated `for` loop.

Comment: You are right, but the requirement is something unusual